# centering svg/div to the center using bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

when I try to center this box to the center it goes to the center left. I have been trying for the past week and nothing has worked. I tried to do it using css by posiitoning it absolute but that ruined the responsive design.

HTML;

```
<body class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark py-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand mx-auto"><h2 style="color: white;">Name</h2></div>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#burger"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="burger">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#python" class="nav-link px-3"><h2 style="color: white;">Python</h2></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-3"><h2 style="color: white;">Name</h2></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#html&css" class="nav-link px-3"><h2 style="color: white;">Html&Css</h2></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Secion One-->
    <section class="bg-dark d-flex align-items-center flex-1 text-light p-5 p-lg-0 text-center text-md-start">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
                <h1 class="hi">Design made by the <span style="color: #F23DFF;">youth</span></h1>
            </div>
                <div class="align-items-center text-center position-relative position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle-y">
                    <h3 class="languages">About</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="align-items-center text-center position-relative position-absolute top-50 end-0 translate-middle-y">
                    <h3 class="languages">Langs</h3>
                </div>
        </div>            
    </section>
    <!--section2-->
    <section>
        <div class="container position-absolute h-100">
          <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 600" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width="600" height="600" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
      </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Here is the css if that helps

CSS;
```@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .navbar-brand{
    display: block;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
  .navbar-brand{
    display: none;
  }
}

html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-1{
  flex: 1;
}
.languages{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: add the related CSS into the question by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can give parents flex classes to solve your problem.

‍‍‍`display: flex; justify-content: center;`

And related codes . . .

Comment: parent flex classes?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).